# Why is my character pool empty after installing War of the Chosen?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I just booted up X-Com 2: War of the Chosen for the first time, but my character pool is empty, and there's nothing in the "Import Character" tab but a Developer Pool.

Where did my characters go?

Comment: This is similar to how Enemy Unknown and Enemy Within worked too, they are separate games. It also makes it possible for people to complete their pre-WotC campaigns without WotC interfering. There have been changes to the character creation system (e.g. eye color is new, afaik), so the new character pool would not necessarily be compatible with the old game (and vice versa).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the major changes added in War of the Chosen (WOTC) there was actually a second folder added for the game in the `Documents\my games` folder (path will be different on a non-windows machine). `Documents\my games\XCOM2` is for the base game, and `Documents\my games\XCOM2 War of the Chosen` is for the expansion. If you take a look inside these folders you'll see a whole bunch of configuration files, including a separate character pool folder for both the base game and WOTC.

So in order to use your character pools you first need to create a character pool file for them by booting up the base game and navigating to the character pool page via the main menu. Once there you just check off all the characters you want to copy over, and then click "Export Selection". You can either add them to an existing character pool or create a new one. Once you've done that a character pool file will show up in:

`Documents\my games\XCOM2\XComGame\CharacterPool\Importable` (it's a .bin extension).

Copy over all the files you want to transfer to:

`Documents\my games\XCOM2 War of the Chosen\XComGame\CharacterPool\Importable`

After you copy the files boot up WOTC. Open up the character pool page, and click the import character tab. Then you just select the character pools you want to create, and then either import the entire pool or individual characters from the pool.